# Bitbucket commit history shows "commit request failed"

Tags: git, bitbucket

I see the following on the bitbucket commit logs page:
[image]
The top commit is marked as **M** and it appears faded.
When I hover over the commit id it shows `commit request failed`
I am not sure what that means and if it failed, why is it even appearing in the bitbucket commit history?
When I run the command `git log` this commit does appear at the top with a message like `Merge: commit-id1 commit-id2`